# extract words from column according to range defined in second column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame containing text in one column and specified windows of interest in a tuple in another column. Consider this example.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['date', 'name', 'text', 'tuple'],
                  data = [['2011-01-01', "Peter",    "Das ist nicht vielversprechend.",            (101, 0, 3)],
                          ['2012-01-01', "Michelle", "Du bist nicht misstrauisch.",                (101, 1, 3)],
                          ['2013-01-01', "Michelle", "Das ist eine vertrauenserweckende Aussage.", (101, 0, 1)],
                          ['2014-01-01', "Peter",    "Ich bin sehr nervös.",                       (101, 1, 3)]])
```

Ignoring the first entry of the tuple, I would now like to extract the word span defined in elements 1 & 2 (zero-indexed, excluding the second number) in the tuple from the column text and add this as a new column (`words_of_interest`).

For example, from line 1, this should yield words 0-2 (up to and excl. word number 3):
Expected output:

```
"Das ist nicht", 
"bist nicht",
"Das"
"bin sehr"
```

I have tried various variations of `.astype(str).str.split().str[i]` for the strings and `.str.get(1)` for the span to no avail. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach:

```
df["result"] = [" ".join(text.split()[start:end]) for text, (_, start, end) in zip(df["text"], df["tuple"])]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
         date      name  ...        tuple         result
0  2011-01-01     Peter  ...  (101, 0, 3)  Das ist nicht
1  2012-01-01  Michelle  ...  (101, 1, 3)     bist nicht
2  2013-01-01  Michelle  ...  (101, 0, 1)            Das
3  2014-01-01     Peter  ...  (101, 1, 3)       bin sehr

[4 rows x 5 columns]
```

**UPDATE**
If there are nan values in the column tuple, you could do:

```
tuples = [(None, None, None) if pd.isna(v) else v for v in df["tuple"]]
df["result"] = [" ".join(text.split()[start:end]) if start is not None else np.nan for text, (_, start, end) in
                zip(df["text"], tuples)]
print(df)
```

Comment: This works amazingly, thank you! Just one issue: the column `tuple` also contains `NaN`s in the real data that result in `TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable float object` - what's the easiest way to resolve this? :)

Comment: @Ivo What would the output be in that case? I mean how do you slice the string?

Comment: Sorry, `NaN`s in `tuple` should yield `NaN` in `result`. Thank you! :)

Comment: Great, this works without an issue! Thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 3):

Quite straight forward with `apply`:

```
df['out'] = df.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x['text'].split()[x['tuple'][1]:x['tuple'][2]]),
         axis=1)
```

Comment: This works amazingly, thank you! Just one issue: the column `tuple` also contains `NaNs`in the real data that result in a `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` - what'd be the easiest way to fix this? :)